# Angular how do I filter the data from an observable using rxjs pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I make a call to a method called getWorkOrders() in my service file which in turn makes a call to the server to fetch the records.

Here is my service. I am using the new HttpClient.

```
export class BackendServices {
  private BASE_URL ='http://localhost:3000/backend';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getWorkOrders(){
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '/getworkorders/');
 }
}
```

Component.ts file

```
private woSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IWorkOrders[]>([]);
    getWorkOrders() {
        this.bs.getWorkOrders()
          .subscribe((data: any) =>
            this.woSubject.next(data),
        );
      }
```

From the component getWorkOrders method how do I filter the data from all the records that was fetched from the server. I understand that it is using pipe & the filter rxjs operators, but not sure how to put it together.

[image]

Comment: did you try with filter?

Comment: I get a squiggly when I try the filter. I have imported filter this way, import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'; I have editted my post with the filter showing the squiggly.

Comment: See my answer - at the point here you are filtering an array, not an rxjs observable so you need to do const filterData  = data.filter(data => data.crew === 'FFM')

Comment: also, just be careful in the filter to make sure you use an == or === comparison rather than the = assignment operator as you have in your example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to filter the workorders that come from the server using an rxjs filter you will need to turn the array of workorders into an observable of workorders, eg.

```
export class BackendServices {
    private BASE_URL ='http://localhost:3000/backend';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getWorkOrders(){
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '/getworkorders/')
                   .pipe(map((data) => Observable.from(data));
    }
}

private woSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IWorkOrders[]>([]);
    getWorkOrders() {
        this.bs.getWorkOrders()
          .pipe(
              filter(data => data.timestamp > 123456786 ),
              toArray()
           )
          .subscribe((data: any) =>
               this.woSubject.next(data),
           );
        }
```

The alternative is just to filter the array in a map using the standard array filter, eg.

```
export class BackendServices {
    private BASE_URL ='http://localhost:3000/backend';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getWorkOrders(){
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '/getworkorders/');
    }
}

private woSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IWorkOrders[]>([]);
    getWorkOrders() {
        this.bs.getWorkOrders()
          .pipe(map(data => data.filter(workorder => workrder.timestamp > 123456786) )
          .subscribe((data: any) =>
               this.woSubject.next(data),
           );
        }
```

One question I would ask is why you are pushing the result of the observable subscription into the behavior subject? Generally if you are pushing results from a subscription into another observable you can achieve the same thing by combining observables instead

Comment: Forgot in the first example that if you want the final result to still be an array you will have to use the toArray operator after the filter - have added this in

Comment: That was really nice of you, thanks for the detailed explanation. I have editted my picture again. I have imported the operators this way import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';. Not sure still I get that red line. Check the picture

Comment: see if 
.pipe(map((data: IWorkOrders[] ) => data.filter(workorder => workrder.crew === 'FFM') )
fixes it

Comment: you are using the filter option from array.prototype here, which has nothing to do with rxjs, so you don't need to import it - but there was no type annotation so no indication to IDE that this was an array so I suspect that was the reason for the squiggly

Comment: This worked for me; However, make sure you use the correct map. I initially imported the wrong one. You want: import { map } from rxjs/operators;